# AWS - Retrieve logs from my .Net Core App

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have used AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a simple .Net Core app to a Windows INstance. However it is not working on AWS as it is working on my local machine. I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error but I cannot see the message/stack trace.

Trying to get the logs, I have followed [this documentantion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html), I have logged into the EC2 instance but my application is not deployed to the `inetpub\wwwroot` and the logs on the `C:\Program Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\logs\` are about the deploy.

How can I find out what is wrong with my application?

Comment: Could you instead [configure your app to display the error information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling) and redeploy to AWS?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That actually helped _A_ lot :D